# proof by definition of limit

Tags: limits

I got stuck while proving a limit by definition.

I wish to prove that:

$$\frac{n^2-n+2}{3n^2+2n-4} =\frac{1}{3} $$

so by using the limit definition:

$$\left|\frac{n^2-n+2}{3n^2+2n-4} -\frac{1}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{-5(n-2)}{3(3n^2+2n-4)}\right| $$

I have to show that from some $n$ this is smaller than $\epsilon$. Any suggestions how to continue from here?

Comment: Informally, notice that now the denominator has higher degree than the numerator, thus it grows much faster than the numerator. Formally, you can use polynomial division to show it.

Comment: There are a couple of mistakes or conceptual problems: for one, you're missing $\lim_{n \to \infty}$. Second, when you write, "I have to show that from some $n$ this is smaller than $\epsilon$", you need to be more precise:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $\left|\frac{-5(n-2)}{3(3n^2+2n-4)}\right| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $|n-2|<n$ and for $n\ge2$,

$$3n^2+2n-4\ge 3n^2$$

Comment: that did it, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your algebra is correct, at this point, the very last expression is  $ \leq \frac{5n}{9n^2}$ which is $\frac{5}{9n}$.

Per the comment below, the inequality fails at $n=1$. But the goal of the $\epsilon$ proof is for the difference to be below $\epsilon$ when $n$ is large. So, the inequality holds for $n \gg 1$.

Take the integer $N$ that is bigger than $\frac{9}{5\epsilon}$. Or, if one wants to be careful based on the comment, take $N \geq \max(10, \frac{9}{5\epsilon})$

Then for $n > N$, the difference will be smaller than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Not quite.  For $n=1$, $3n^2+2n-4=1<3n^2=3$.  So, you need to ensure that $n>1$.

Comment: Sure, I will edit that the inequality holds for "large" $n$.

Comment: Yes, it holds for all $n>1$.